# Django - leaving messages to (offline) users using the new messages framework

Tags: django

So `message_set` is deprecated in favor of the new messages framework. The good old `message_set` allowed me to leave messages to offline users (for example, when I do some stuff in a cron job I may want to notify some user about that). Now take a glance at the new framework and it seems that a message can only be added to the `request` object.

Have I missed anything or is the functionality of adding a message to a `user` object gone, which means I'll have to roll my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're missing anything. The functionality of adding messages to a `user` object will be deprecated in Django 1.2, and removed completely in 1.4 (from the django authentication docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/auth/#messages)). And none of the new messaging storage backends are pre-rolled for persistent (e.g. database or file storage) of messages.

But all is not lost. I see nothing in the new messaging storage backend code that insists that you provide a valid request when storing a message (so storing a message from, for instance, a cron job would work). If I were you, I would roll my own backend that stashes messages in a database table.

**Edit: How you might implement this**

If your ok with implementing the offline message storage as a bolt on to one of the new messaging backends one possible approach is:

1. Define a message Model

   ```
   class UserMessage(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
     message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ```
2. Manually create UserMessages from your cron job

   ```
   def some_func_in_my_cron_job():
     ...
     UserMessage.create(user=some_user, message="Something happened")
     ...
   ```
3. Define a new message storage engine, overriding one of the existing engines, and redefine _get()

   ```
   from django.contrib.messages.storage.session import SessionStorage

   class MyStorageEngine(SessionStorage):
     def _get(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if hasattr(self.request, "user") and self.request.user.is_authenticated():
           offline_messages = UserMessage.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
           # and delete the messages from the database
       else:
           offline_messages = None

     other_messages = super(MyStorageEngine, self)._get(*args, **kwargs)

     # all_messages = combine offline_messages and other_messages

     return all_messages
   ```
4. Turn on your new message engine in settings:

   ```
   MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'myproj.custom_message_storage.MyStorageEngine'
   ```

With this approach, you won't write to your database backend using the new messaging api, but you can read your manually set messages with it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It should be easy to write a message storage backend. However, binding a message to a user and then displaying it when that user becomes online is complicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Interested in how you solved the issue. please share if you did!

Answer (score 4):

Someone has created a nice implementation of this, possibly based on the accepted answer:

https://github.com/dym/django-offline-messages

```
from offline_messages.utils import create_offline_message, constants

user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
create_offline_message(user, 'Woo, it worked', constants.SUCCESS)
```

The message will be displayed to the user on the next page load.

Answer (score 1):

messages_extends for the django messages framework 
https://github.com/AliLozano/django-messages-extends/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

If your settings.py is using `messages_extends.storages.FallbackStorage`, you can create a persistent message (will display indefinetely until the user clicks `x`), using:

```
import messages_extends
from messages_extends.models import Message
Message.objects.create(user=target_user, level=messages_extends.INFO_PERSISTENT, message='Hey! You will see me until you click X!')
```

Here is the definition for the `Message` model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (messages_extends.DEBUG_PERSISTENT, 'PERSISTENT DEBUG'),
        (messages_extends.INFO_PERSISTENT, 'PERSISTENT INFO'),
        (messages_extends.SUCCESS_PERSISTENT, 'PERSISTENT SUCCESS'),
        (messages_extends.WARNING_PERSISTENT, 'PERSISTENT WARNING'),
        (messages_extends.ERROR_PERSISTENT, 'PERSISTENT ERROR'),
        )
    level = models.IntegerField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
    extra_tags = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The other storages probably just store the message in the memory, so you'd really don't have it in hand.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#configuring-the-message-engine) claim there are 4 different storage engines. The `FallbackStorage` engine writes to the session.

Comment: Yes, it writes to the session, which belongs to a "request".